# Eclipse OpenCV image path doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I tried everything but nothing seems to work here. I just want to read an image using OpendCV. Here is the code:

```
Mat image = Highgui.imread("/src/resources/figures.png");
```

This is in the MainApp.java

[image: Project Structure]

But still getting the same error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cv::cvtColor, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3961
```

The figures.png image is the one that I am trying to get, I put the same file inside and outside the com.ia package, but still nothing works. I tried:

```
Mat image = Highgui.imread("figures.png");
Mat image = Highgui.imread("src/com/ia/figures.png");
Mat image = Highgui.imread("/src/com/ia/figures.png");
Mat image = Highgui.imread("/com/ia/figures.png");
```

And even more combinations, can someone please help me, I am going crazy with this. I also have the same problem with other projects, what is wrong with eclipse's file paths ¿?¿

Comment: Which version of opencv are you using? Which tutorial did you use to include it into eclipse? You could always read the Image into a "File" and see if the reference is empty. Also worth noting execution and debug could use different paths (at least this happens in netbeans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` is because of the OpenCV library not linked, you can first load the lib like this:

```
System.loadLibrary("lib_name");
```

And try again.

Comment: You are right, but still I have the problem with the image :(

Comment: You can put the image outside of the source, you can create a folder name=img and under the project folder (the same level as src folder), and then put the image over there, and then direct the path to that image ("/img/imge.png")

Comment: If you put anything inside the src folder, then it will be compiled by the compiler to the bin folder the same as .java files which compiled to .class files. and then you can read those resources bu ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("resource_name").

Comment: It must work. You can create a folder under the project folder and then put the image in this folder and then try this: `Mat image = Highgui.imread("img/figures.png");` But if you still have the problem with UnsatisfiedLinkError then you can first solve this, then go ahead step by step.

Comment: Not the exact solution, but it helped.